# In a reduction with additive but nonlinear blow up can I still get APX-Hardness?

Tags: complexity-theory, theory, reduction, approximation

I'm not entirely sure how to phrase this so first I'll give an example and then, in analogy to the example, try and state my question.

A standard example of an L-reduction is showing bounded degree independent set (for concreteness say instantiated as G = (V,E), B $\ge$ 3 is the bound on degree) is APX complete by L - reduction to max 2 SAT. It works by creating a clause for each edge and a clause for each vertex, the idea being in our simulation by MAX 2 SAT every edge clause will be satisfied and it's optimum is:

```
OPT = |E| + |Maximum Ind. Set|
```

Since the degree is bounded, |Max Ind. Set| is \Theta(|E|) and we get an L-Reduction.

Now my question is suppose I have two problems A, which is APX-Complete, and B which is my target problem. Let the optimum of A be \Theta(m) and my solution in B

```
OPT_B = p(m) + OPT_A
```

where p is some polynomial with deg(p) > 1. I no longer have an L-reduction, my question is do get anything? Can it be a PTAS reduction? I hope the question is clear, thanks.